# How can I repair a damaged seam on leather sofa

Tags: repair, furniture, upholstery

See the attached image below, any idea how I can repair this problem myself?

[image: loose stitch]

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

- Use the thread that comes from hole to tie the thread that goes to bottom left corner as per picture.
- Use the left back portion of thread to tighten with knot before and after the newly tied one.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the tie just came undone. I would get a some tweezers and take hold of the eyelet lace and try to tie it around the stitch to hole it back in place. You could try google or you tube to see what would be the best knot to use.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find a tutorial online for this particular stitch. If you have a YouTube vid or page you found that would be great!